# facebook long-live access using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dotnetopenauth

i am creating an application in asp.net, which will use the user's facebook data using its api's,
but in order to access the Fb api's we need to perform the OAuth(2.0) first.
i did that too by using the DotNetOpenAuth library in the following code:

```
private static readonly FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient
    {
        ClientIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fbAppID"],
        ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fbSecret"]),
    };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IAuthorizationState authorization = client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
        if (authorization == null)
        {
            // Kick off authorization request
            client.RequestUserAuthorization();                
        }
        else
        {
            var req = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppID"] + "&client_secret=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppSecret"] + "&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken));


            var request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken));
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var graph = FacebookGraph.Deserialize(responseStream);
                    this.nameLabel.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(graph.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

my question here is, how can i get the long-lived access token of facebook using the DotNetOpenAuth library, so that user do not need to login again and again and i can store that somewhere.
please help me.

Comment: i sent a request to this url too:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fbAppID"] + "&client_secret=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fbAppSecret"] + "&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken)

but i am getting an error i.e. invalid character 'a', thats weired

Answer (score 0):

If possible use Facebook SDK for .Net to create access token for long time. may be 60 days.

using Facebook;

var cl = new FacebookClient(short_lived_access_token);

```
            dynamic result = client.Post("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = "your app id",
                client_secret = "your app secret",
                grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
                fb_exchange_token = client.AccessToken
            });
```

var long_lived_access_token = result.access_token;